# Generar 4 colores aleatorios de entre 6 y asignarlos a 4 botones (android/Java)

Tags: java, android-studio

muy buenas!
Soy nueva por aquí....
Necesitaba un poco de ayuda, si sois tan amables. Estoy haciendo un juego en Android (un mastermind). Tengo 6 colores distintos y necesito generar una combinacion aleatoria que me genere 4 colores (sin repetir) y asignarlos a 4 botones.
Mi código, genera 4 colores sin repetir. Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema lo tengo en los "if", que asigno a 2 botones 2 colores distintos (imageButtonAdivinar3 e imageButtonAdivinar4), por lo que si salen los mismos colores que hay dentro del buttonAdiviar1 por ejemplo, nome lo rellena. Mejor pongo el código, porque no sé explicarme bien....

```
    public int obtenerCombinacionAleatoria() {

    ArrayList<Integer> listaNumeros = new ArrayList();
    int totalNumerosAgenerar = 0;
    int numero = 0;

    while (totalNumerosAgenerar != 4) {
        numero = ((int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        if (!listaNumeros.contains(numero)) {
            totalNumerosAgenerar++;
            listaNumeros.add(numero);

        }
        if (numero == 1) {
            imageButtonAdivinar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.amarilloprimero32);
        }
        if (numero == 2) {
            imageButtonAdivinar2.setImageResource(R.drawable.azulprimero32);
        }
        if (numero == 3) {
            imageButtonAdivinar3.setImageResource(R.drawable.lilaprimero32);
        }
        if (numero == 4) {
            imageButtonAdivinar4.setImageResource(R.drawable.rojoprimero32);
        }
        if (numero == 5) {
            imageButtonAdivinar3.setImageResource(R.drawable.rosaprimero32);
        }
        if (numero == 6) {
            imageButtonAdivinar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.verdeprimero32);
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

En la imagen, el botón gris no está rellenado. Esto es porque
han salido el num 6 y el num 1, que estan asignados al mismo botón
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que obtengo es el siguiente: "array required, but Setfound"

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías intentar el siguiente algoritmo.

```
public void setColors(){
    Set<Integer> indexColors = getFourRandomColors();
    final int[] colors = {R.drawable.amarilloprimero32,
            R.drawable.azulprimero32,
            R.drawable.lilaprimero32,
            R.drawable.rojoprimero32,
            R.drawable.rosaprimero32,
            R.drawable.verdeprimero32
    };

    imageButtonAdivinar1.setImageResource(colors[indexColors[0]]);
    imageButtonAdivinar2.setImageResource(colors[indexColors[1]]);
    imageButtonAdivinar3.setImageResource(colors[indexColors[2]]);
    imageButtonAdivinar4.setImageResource(colors[indexColors[3]]];

}

public Set<Integer> getFourRandomColors(){
    Set<Integer> set = Collections.emptySet();
    int color = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    while(set.size() < 4){
        color = random.nextInt(6);
        set.add(color);
    }
    return set;
}
```